# The == and != operators can be overloaded to return types other than bool. Strange but true

Tags: c#-3.0

I just saw in the C# hidden things that the bool operators can be overloaded and can return any data type that we want. Can any one explain me about that.

Comment: Explain you what exactly?  And: You Ain't Gonna Need It.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example of where it's used: [SqlInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint32.op_equality.aspx) has `==` overloaded to return [`SqlBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.aspx). This allows for SQL-style equality comparisons with null (as `SqlInt32` and `SqlBoolean` both allow for representations of null, even before `Nullable<T>` was introduced).

Comment: Just a small clarification it maybe silly. Can you let me know whether the == and != operator can only be overloaded just to return null. Can you give me the example, as i am not seeing anything. Thanks

Comment: @Adidas: It's returning a `SqlBoolean` value, which can represent null using `SqlBoolean.Null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Similar to this, can we convert the same to something like SqlBoolean.ToString() else it can only be applied for Null

Comment: @Adidas: Um, I couldn't quite parse your sentence... You can call ToString on SqlBoolean.Null, but I don't know what the result will be. Try it!